# Is my wall strong enough to hold up a 16 ft wide roof extension, if not how can it be?

Tags: walls, framing, foundation

I've got a gable roof cabin on unrestricted land that I'm looking to extend over to have an outside reprieve from the rain. I'm not worried about the roof as I've done something similar in the past but I've never built a wall with exposed framework. Instead of using 2x4s to build a frame wall I intend to go with posts attached directly to footer blocks. the posts will be 13ft away from the current wall of the cabin. the roof is 16ft wide with 2ft overhang on each side. the roof will consist of (9) 16 foot long 2x6s, 2x4s for purlins, and corrugated metal roofing. I've attached an ms paint image of the current design of the wall. the posts, 45 degree supports, and top plate will all be 4x4s.[image]

Comment: Where are you?  If you have a frost level, then you probably want the wall side to float also(not anchored to the house/building).  No frost level, then probably can treat it as a deck for anchoring.

Comment: If wanting to know if the wall will hold, will need to describe how the wall is built.  Most people will think/assume standard 2x4/2x6 stud walls on a foundation/slab.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm in Hawaii on the big island. As far as the wall is built I was gonna follow the diagram that I posted. Though I may add some 2x4s across the bottom for shear strength.

Comment: gable so there will be a triangle peaking above the middle post?

Comment: The roof it's currently coming off of is gable. The roof section that is connecting to the posts is uniform in its height at all points

Answer (score 0):

While not an engineer, your design sound very solid for just a corrugated metal roof. Being on unrestricted land I'm assuming you have no particular codes that need to be met.

Not knowing the soil conditions in your area or freeze situation I can't comment on that.  There is little wind uplift protection, but that may not be an issue where you are as well.

To your question regarding the frame of your wall, yes you can do that.

I'm a bit paranoid of wind issues being in Florida.  If it were my doing I would anchor the posts to poured concrete piers that were about 24" deep and use [Simpson hurricane ties](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Simpson-Strong-Tie-Hurricane-Tie-Z-MAX/3047195?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-bdm-_-ggl-_-LIA_BDM_103_Roofing-Gutters-_-3047195-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2eilBhCCARIsAG0Pf8tKZ8koP36ffb3ACxusdjKtEIIBN8xVdqbVMvmnrIAlcJJYqeixrlIaAoL9EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) on all the rafters.

Comment: As they say location, location, location.  I am in what might be called a tame weather section, but have seen a couple of down drafts and had an EF-0 tornado close by that killed a person, so hurricane ties might be useful anywhere.

Comment: Cool I imagined as much but wasn't sure. Wind shouldn't be too bad since I'm nestled in a tropical forest up a mountain a bit. But I'll think how to adjust for lift from wind. Volcanic rock, so drilling deep anchors isn't so easy.